Sendbird usage reports
We are building a small chat and calls mobile application using Sendbird and React Native for several of our customers. Currently during the proof-of-concept phase, all of the users are in the same Sendbird application, but are being separated by a unique per company ID stored in Sendbird as a custom attribute.
This is working fine at the moment, but our concern is how would we go about getting usage reports for each company separately? Has anyone faced this issue and knows how? Or is there a better way to do it?
Thank you in advance for any help.
